# Media player not playing any sound

Tags: java, android

I am developing a simple calculator for a device, there I am using mediaplayer to play some sound when a button is pressed using

```
media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wipe);
            media.start();
```

and in a reset button i am releasing it with

```
media.release();
```

but after some button clicks it stops playing any sound. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this,

```
MediaPlayer media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.wipe);
            media.start();
```

On reset button write like:

```
media.release();
media.reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaPlayer is not a good option when you are playing small sound effects as the user can click on multiple buttons very soon and you will have to create a MP object for all of them **which doesnt happen *synchronously***. That is why you are not hearing sounds for every click. 
Go for the SoundPool Class which allows you to keep smaller sounds loaded in memory and you can play them any time you want without any lag which you would feel in a mediaplayer. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html
Here is a nice tutorial : http://www.anddev.org/using_soundpool_instead_of_mediaplayer-t3115.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to play your media always in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

On click of reset button , also use media.reset(); after media.release();